# How to use distinct and limit together

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query. I need to get last value from columns Lat,Lng from my table but serial_number column needs to be distinct.

How to make such a query?

This is needed as I am using this coordinates to load it to Google map. So when the Google maps loads I need to have a marker on each last coordinates where vehicle is.

Comment: what are the "I need to get last Lat,Lng "...?

Comment: is serial_numer field of same table? Also it will be better if you define the structure in your question

Comment: where does limit come in the picture?

Comment: I was thinking something as limit one last row

Comment: Can you display the structure of that table?

Comment: okay so I have a `ID|Latitude|Longitude|serial_number|time` ... and some other columns

Comment: id is unique too same as serial_number

Comment: What is holding you fetching last record of Latitude and Longitude with Distinct ..... what error you are getting?

Comment: I don't know how to make such a query

Comment: @denonth: do you want to retrieve last record for each distinct `serial_number`?

Comment: @Quassnoi yes I want to get the last LAtitude and Longitude record that have certain serial_number

Comment: @denonth: a *certain* serial_number or *all* serial_numbers? Is `serial_number` a parameter to the query?

Comment: @Quassnoi all, yes I will have the query with sending one as parameter too. So as I understood correctly. Good thing would be to save lat,lng and serial number in some array so when user wants to follow certain vehicle query only sends serial_number and I fetch only last results from the table.. Your answer is good. can you give me example with sending as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT serial_number
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.serial_number = md.serial_number
        ORDER BY
                mi.time DESC, mi.id DESC
        LIMIT   1
        )
```

Create an index on `(serial_number, time, id)` for this to work fast.

If you want to retrieve the last record for a certain serial_number, just use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   serial_number = :my_serial_number
ORDER BY
        time DESC, id DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: Hi your code really worked for me. But I have one question. How can I get a username from some other table which is not in this table. For example: This table has a `user_code` which is is the same column as in the other table from which I want to get the user name. Something like this table `m` that we have `m.user_code = b.user_code` and in the first select I would have a `b.Name` how to make that?

Comment: Can you please help me? I really need a help and this is a min for you

Comment: @denonth: please post your issue as a separate question, I'll look it when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

1#
Assuming that max ID will always give you last lat and lon, the query becomes quite simple -

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table t2
where t2.id IN 
 (
   SELECT max(t1.id)
   FROM table t1
   GROUP BY t1.serial_number
 )
```

---

2# 
If you need to consider time also, then you will need to do it this way. Here, in the inner query, max_time of each serial_number is obtained. Then this max_time and serial_number is joined with the outer table time and serial_number respectively, to get distinct records with last lat and lon.

```
SELECT *
FROM table t2, 
 (
   SELECT max(t1.time) max_time, t1.serial_number
   FROM table t1
   GROUP BY t1.serial_number
 ) new_table
WHERE t2.time=new_table.max_time
AND t2.serial_number=new_table.serial_number
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select distinct serial_number, *
from table t
inner join table t1 on t1.serial_number = t.serial_number and t1.id = (select max id from table t2 where t2.serial_number = t1.serial_number)
```